# GAE Datastore API drop-in replacement

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mongodb

I'm trying to find a similar solution with this:

[Drop-in replacement for AppEngine Datastore API](https://github.com/mdirolf/mongo-appengine-connector) (Python)

However this API seems to be outdated already, is there any effort to do Datastore API using MongoDB as backend for Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to find a drop-in replacement, with **JBoss CapeDwarf** there is no more vendor-locking for the Appengine Platform:

See:

http://www.jboss.org/capedwarf

Answer (score 1):

Appscale

http://appscale.cs.ucsb.edu/

Commercial version supposedly coming soon:

http://appscale.com/

Comment: Right, however I don't think that the Datastore API of AppScale is based in Ruby not Java

Comment: wtf?  ruby?  Try clicking on the link.

Comment: i mean, the underlying API code, I've seen the AppScale code and it build wit Ruby... anyway, nevermind I found a better solution already

Comment: Care to share?  Then mark your question as answered or close it?